# Jetpack Compose - how to adjust the padding depending on the height of another component?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a component set with `Modifier.wrapContentHeight()` which height has different height depending on its content. I want to adjust other component's padding to the first component height dynamically. I tried something like this:

```
       var height = 0
       val resourceContentBottomPadding = height + 16

       LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = height.dp),
        ) { /.../ }

       Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    height = it.size.height
                }
        ) {
            if (something)
                SomeComposeElement()

            Button()
        }
```

Unfortunately it changes nothing.

Comment: `var height = 0` this would never trigger a recomposition and value is always 0. before trying anything else try changing it to `var height by remember{mutableStateOf(0)`. But this approach by nature will trigger a composition and you are likely to observe jump in position of Composables

Answer (score -1):

If you put your LazyColumn and Column inside an ancestor Column and set  `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(1f)` for your LazyColumn it will only occupy space after Column is laid out which is total height - height of the Column